# Cursor theme changes to default when clicking on most buttons

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, mouse, themes, cursor

My cursor changes to breeze when I click on most menus/buttons.

For example, if I click the Hamburger Menu on Firefox, the cursor theme changes from the current theme I have to breeze, then it changes back as soon as I move the cursor, however this causes flickering if right clicking to open context menus.

The only current way to stop this from happening is to either change the size of the cursor and putting it back to the size you had it, or by switching cursors and applying the one you want back, this happens anytime you restart your computer, it happens on all 3 of my laptops running Kubuntu 22.04, any help would be appreciated.